# form_widget submit doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to customize my form created with formBuilder.

My form is working well when i display it with `{{ form(comment) }}` but doesn't work anymore with `{{ form_widget(comment.MYMETHOD) }}`

I display my form like this :

```
<form class="commentForm">
    <ul>
        <li class="commentFormArea">{{ form_widget(comment.commentaires) }}
        </li>
        <li class="commentFormsubmit">{{ form_widget(comment.save) }}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My controller

```
 public function postsAction(Request $request)
{
    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('NastycodeFrontBundle:Publication')
    ;
    $posts = $repository->findBy(array(), array(), 10);

    $commentaires = new Commentaires();

    $comment = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $commentaires)
        ->add('commentaires', 'textarea')
        ->add('save',      'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    // On fait le lien Requête <-> Formulaire
    // À partir de maintenant, la variable $commentaires contient les valeurs entrées dans le formulaire par le visiteur
    $comment->handleRequest($request);

    // On vérifie que les valeurs entrées sont correctes
    // (Nous verrons la validation des objets en détail dans le prochain chapitre)
    if ($comment->isValid()) {
        // On l'enregistre notre objet $commentaires dans la base de données, par exemple
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($commentaires);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');

        // On redirige vers la page de visualisation de l'annonce nouvellement créée
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('nastycode_comment_code', array('id' => $commentaires->getId())));
    }

    $user = $this->getUser();
    return $this->render('NastycodeFrontBundle:Posts:posts.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'comment' => $comment->createView(),
    ));
}
```

When i submit my form, it generate this url

> /web/app_dev.php/nastycodes?form[commentaires]=MYCOMMENT&form[save]=

Instead of this

> /web/app_dev.php/nastycodes?id=1

I have no idea why my submit doesn't work when i don't display all the form.

Do you guys know what is the problem and how i can fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `method="post"` to the `<form>` tag, the default method of form is GET.

When you use `{{ form(comment) }}` it generates all fields of the form in the template. Try to add `form_rest(comment)` before form closing tag `</form>` ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables)) to ensure you didn't omit something.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of `Symfony2` are you using but since `v2.3` there are `form_start()` and `form_end()` `Twig` functions which could be used to print form open and form close tags, including its attributes.

You would, however, need to do this:

```
$comment = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $commentaires)
        ->setMethod("POST") // <--- THIS
        ->add('commentaires', 'textarea')
        ->add('save',      'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;
```

And then:

```
{{ form_start(comment) }}
    <ul>
        <li class="commentFormArea">{{ form_widget(comment.commentaires) }}
        </li>
        <li class="commentFormsubmit">{{ form_widget(comment.save) }}</li>
    </ul>
{{ form_end(comment) }}
```

By default, `form_end` automatically invokes `form_rest(form)`...

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.6.4, i have tested your method, this work too, thanks.